# Why does my web page lose the ability to receive signalr messages

Tags: signalr

Basically I have 3 apps.  A web app, Nservicebus, and a signalr self hosting server for my hubs.  I am currently using signalr version .4.  Basically the web app initiates a connection with the self hosted server on page load.  The User does an action which sends a command down the service bus.  The service bus then connects to the signalr server to notify all the web clients.

**My Web page:**

```
<script src="http://localhost:8081/test/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var myHub;  

    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8081/test/signalr/hubs';

    $(function () {
        myHub = $.connection.userAccountHub;

        myHub.ChangeNameUpdated = function (connId) {
            alert("recieved signalr message");          
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            var myClientId = $.connection.hub.id;
            setCookie("srconnectionid", myClientId);
        });
    });

</script>
```

**My SignalR server:**

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Debug.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
        Debug.AutoFlush = true;

        string url = "http://localhost:8081/test/";
        var server = new Server(url);


        server.EnableHubs();
        server.Start();


        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);

        while (true)
        strong text{
            ConsoleKeyInfo ki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**My Hub inside my Signalr server project**

```
 public class UserAccountHub : Hub
    {

        public void UsersNameChanged(string passedThroughConnectionId)
        {
            Clients.ChangeNameUpdated(passedThroughConnectionId);
        }
    }
```

**My Call from my nservicebus**

```
        //connect to signalRServer
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081/test/signalr/hubs");
        IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateProxy("SignalRServer.Hubs.UserAccountHub");

        //Credentials are inherited from the application
        connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        var test = message.GetHeader("signalrConnectionId");


        connection.Start().Wait();
        myHub.Invoke("UsersNameChanged", message.GetHeader("signalrConnectionId")).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            //for debuging purposes
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "An error occurred during the method call {0}",
                    task.Exception.GetBaseException());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully called MethodOnServer");
            }
        });
```

I open up 2 browsers.  I initiate the process on the second browser, and only the first one receives notifications.  The second browser doesnt.

I don't see any issues that stand out when I run fiddler either.

Is there a better approach to this implementation, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is any of that working?

`var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081/test/signalr/hubs");`

The above line is incorrect. You Create a connection to the hub url like this:

`var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081/test/");`

Same for your javascript hub url, it should be:

$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8081/test/signalr';

Comment: It works "sometimes" which made me think I was doing the connection part correctly.  If I use just 1 browser everything appears to work correctly (the first time), if I try and do a second action, it stops receiving notifications.  But then if I refresh the page from scratch, it will get 1 notification then not receive any more.  After checking out fiddler on a different project I have, it seems to be a difference I see.  This solution stops long polling after it receives the first notification.

Comment: I will check out using the connections as you specified.

Comment: That's strange. As it looks like it shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Thanks david, your comments got me going in the right direction.  I upgraded to .5 and then took a nice long look at the how I was dealing with the connection strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK!  David's comments got me going in the right direction. Also noticed this was updated, didnt notice this before.  [Scroll to the bottom for the cross domain support](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs)

1.)  Updated to version .5

2.) Modified my connection information in javascript to

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8081/test/signalr';

$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling', xdomain: true }).done(function () {
    //alert("staring hub connection:  " + $.connection.hub.id);
    setCookie("srconnectionid", $.connection.hub.id);
});
```

3.) I had to change the `HubConnection`

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081/test/");
```

4.) I had to change the `IHubProxy`

```
IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateProxy("UserAccountHub");
```